# How do I install a specific iPhone simulator SDK version in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

A couple weeks ago I was working on a project that referenced the iPhoneSimulator 8.2 SDK.  Today I went to continue work on the project and suddenly I can't run the simulator.  I receive the following error message:

> ERROR! Can't locate iPhoneSimulator SDK 8.2 at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk'

Sure enough, the simulator SDK doesn't exist in that directory anymore.  So I opened up XCode, went to the downloads window and saw it wasn't installed anymore.  I have no idea how that happened, but I'm guessing XCode updated itself and removed it.  So, I download and install the 8.2 SDK again.  However, when it finished, my project still wouldn't run: I received the exact same error.  Upon inspection of the file system, I see that XCode actually installed the 8.3 SDK, not 8.2, even though the XCode GUI says it installed 8.2.

I'm running XCode 6.3 (which is weird because I see 6.3 was only released a couple days ago and I haven't installed or upgraded XCode in over a month).

Is there a way to download a specific version of the iPhoneSimulator SDK and manually install it?

Comment: You "download and install the 8.2 SDK" ?  Do you mean you downloaded and installed the 8.2 simulator runtime?  Where are you seeing this error?

Answer (score 3):

You run an iOS Simulator runtime in the iOS Simulator
You build against an iOS Simulator SDK.

Unfortunately this is confusing because the SDK and runtime are located at the same place inside the Xcode.app bundle.

What you want to do is build against the latest iOS Simulator SDK (iOS 8.3 as of Xcode 6.3) and run your app in a simulated device with the iOS 8.2 simulator runtime.

You can install the iOS 8.2 simulator runtime from within Xcode by going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I know it sounds confusing because this is actually a RubyMotion project, so the build and run process is done outside of XCode.  At any rate, it is targeting the 8.2 SDK, but I can't seem to get XCode to download and install the 8.2 SDK.  In XCode > Preferences > Downloads it *says* 8.2 SDK, but when I tell it to download it, it *actually* downloads the 8.3 SDK (per what I see in the filesystem).  So, I can't figure out how to get it to actually download 8.2 instead of 8.3

Comment: It should say 8.2 *RUNTIME* in the downloads.  I'll check on that and file a radar if the name is wrong.  Sorry if it was misnamed and confusing.  You only have one SDK, the one that is shipped with Xcode.  It is called iPhoneSimulator.sdk and has a symlink with the current version (iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk).  You probably need to update your RubyMotion project to point to the path without the version in it.

Comment: In the XCode downloads window it says "Components > iOS 8.2 Simulator" (with a checkmark next to it.  I also have the 8.1 and 7.1 simulators.  I don't see anything in downloads that says "runtime".  In my filesystem, I have a `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` folder with `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` and `iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk`.  No `8.2` version.  In my RubyMotion project, I'm not sure how to make it point to the the version without a number.  All I have in my rakefile is `app.sdk_version = "8.2"`

Comment: I'll add that changing my rakefile to point to the 8.3 SDK fixes the issue, but that means everyone else will have to upgrade to the 8.3 SDK.  I don't want to do that -- I just want to build against the 8.2 SDK for now.

Comment: Ok, yes that is correct then.  "iOS 8.2 Simulator" installs the 8.2 runtime.  You don't want nor need the 8.2 SDK.  You should be using the latest SDK.  It sounds like a bug in RubyMotion that it requires an SDK version number.  Change that 8.2 to 8.3 and file a bug report with the RubyMotion developers to address that issue.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  When I install "iOS 8.2 Simulator" it installs the "8.3" SDK, **not** the 8.2 SDK.  That's my whole problem.  The XCode GUI says 8.2, but my filesystem says 8.3.  I can't find any way to install the 8.2 SDK and forcing an upgrade to 8.3 means I have to do a bunch more testing.  I know the 8.2 SDK works because that's what I've been using up until now.  I don't want to build against the 8.3 SDK.

Comment: The 8.3 SDK is installed when you install Xcode.app from the App Store.  When you install the "iOS 8.2 Simulator", /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.2.simruntime is installed.

Comment: Your updated Xcode.app included both a newer SDK (headers and libraries to link against) and toolchain (clang, ld64, etc).  Even if you did slam the 8.2 SDK in there (which isn't supported), you'd still be using a different toolchain than you previously were using, and that would certainly warrant more testing than just an SDK change.